# Are the two kinds of interface of xgboost work completely same?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm currently working on a In Class Competition in Kaggle.
I have read about the official python API reference, and I'm kind of confused about the two kinds of interfaces, especially in grid-search, cross-validation and early-stopping.

In XGBoost API, I can use `xgb.cv()`, which split the whose dataset into two parts to cross validate,  to tune a good hyper parameters and then get the `best_iteration`.
Thus I can adjust the `num_boost_round` to the `best_iteration`. To maximizely utilize the data, I train the whole dataset again with the well-tuned hyper parameters, and then use it to classify. The only defect is I have to write the code of `GridSearch` myself.

ATTENTION: this cross validation set is changed at each fold, so the traning result will have no specific tendency to any part of the data.

But in sklearn, it seem that I can not get `best_iteration` using `clf.fit()` as I do in xgb model. Indeed, `fit()` method has `early_stopping_rounds` and `eval_set` to implement the early stopping part. Many people implement the code like that:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, target_label, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
clf = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, para_grid, scoring='roc_auc', cv=5, \
        verbose=True, refit=True, return_train_score=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=30, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)])
....
clf.predict(something)
```

But problem is that I have split the data into two part at first. The cross validation set will not be changed at each fold. So maybe the result will have a tendency toward this random part of the whole dataset. The same problem also occurs in the grid search, the final parameter may tend to fit
`X_test` and `y_test` more.

I'm fond of the `GridSearchCV` in sklearn, but I also want to get the `eval_set` changed at each fold, just like `xgb.cv` do.  I believe it can utilize the data while preventing overfitting.

How should I do?
I have thought of two ways:

1. using XGB API, and write GridSearch myself.
2. using sklean API, and change the `eval_set` manually at each fold.
   Are there any more convenient methods?

Comment: My first thought is that doing a grid search is not worth your time. `xgb.cv` is perfectly good and will get you 99% of the way to as good a predictor as you're going to get. Grid searching is unlikely to make a substantial difference.

Answer (score -1):

AS you have summarised, both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.

- `xgb.cv` will use the left-out fold for early stopping, thus you do **not** need an additional split into a validation/train sample to determine when to trigger early stopping.
- `GridSearchCV` (or maybe you try out `RandomizedSearchCV`) will handle parameter grid and optimal choice for you.

Note, that it is not a problem to use a fixed sub-sample for early stopping in all CV folds. So i do not think that you have to do anything like "*change the `eval_set` manually at each fold*". The evaluation sample used in early stopping does not directly affect model parameters- it is used to decide when evaluation metric on a hold-out sample stops improving. For the final model you can drop early-stopping- you can see when the model stops with the optimal hyper-parameters using the aforementioned split and then use that number of tree as a fixed parameter in the final model fit.

So at the end it is a matter of taste as in both cases you will need to compromise on something. IMO, the sklearn API is the optimal choice as it allows to use the rest of sklearn tools (e.g. for data pre-processing) in a natural way in a pipeline in CV and it allows a homogeneous interface to model training for various approaches. But at the end it is up to you

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But is it better to use a changed validation set? Just like k-fold is more robust than simply splitting the dataset into two parts. Although, any subset of the data theorectically have the same distribution as the whole dataset, but in fact it's based on the random result, which may be have twisted patterns.

Comment: @YaominChang, yes, it might be better to have a changing sample for the early-stop condition. But it is **not a must**. In this sense the analogy that you made with CV is illustrative- CV helps to get a more robust (and better understood in terms of stability) result, but having it is not a must, because train/test split by itself does not introduce a bias, unless one misuses it.